# No outbound internet on client during PXE installation

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, netinstall

I'm using [this guide](http://clinta.github.io/automated-pxe-ubuntu-installs/)  to do an automated PXE install of Ubuntu on a system. However there is no outbound internet from the client machine and it can't resolve any of the mirrors when it comes time to do that during the installation. I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong using this guide but from what I understand, I shouldn't be having this problem. Has anyone else run into this issue and has some information that would help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that in my DHCP server's dhcpd.conf I had DNS set to resolve to the server rather than the address to my modem. Once that was changed the connection problem was fixed.